# Unidentified Reference to functions in C++

Tags: c++

I'm still trying to get a handle on C++ programming, and I'm trying to compile a code that is meant to create different personnel objects and save book titles to those personnels using trees. I keep getting an:

> unidentified reference to 'insert_Book()'
>
> unidentified reference to 'search_Book()'

in my `insert()` function. Why is this? Thank you!

```
//insert function
void insert(){
    char ch;

    cout << endl << "@Insertion module...............";
    do {
     sub_menu();
     cin >> ch;
     ch = tolower(ch);

     switch(ch) {
        case 'p':   if(insert_personnel() != 0)
                        cout << "@INSERTION OPERATION FAILED." << endl;
                    else
                        cout << "@INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY." << endl;
                        break;
        case 'e':   if(insert_employee() != 0)
                        cout << "@INSERTION OPERATION FAILED." << endl;
                    else
                        cout << "@INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY." << endl;
                        break;
        case 'f':   if(insert_faculty() != 0)
                        cout << "@INSERTION OPERATION FAILED." << endl;
                    else
                        cout << "@INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY." << endl;
                        break;
         case 's': if(insert_student() !=0)
                        cout << "@INSERTION OPERATION FAILED." << endl;
                    else
                        cout <<"@INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY." << endl;
                        break;
         case 'b': if(insert_Book() !=0)
                 cout << "@INSERTION OPERATION FAILED." << endl;
             else
                 cout <<"@INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY." << endl;
                        break;
         case 'g': if (search_Book() !=0)
                 cout << "@INSERTION OPERATION FAILED." << endl;
             else
                 cout <<"@INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY." << endl;
                    break;
        case 'q':   cout << endl << "@Exiting the insertion..." << endl;
                    cin.get();
                    break;
        default:        cout << endl << "@ERROR - Invalid input." << endl;
                    cout << "@Try again....." << endl;
       }
    }
    while (ch != 'q');
}

int search_Book(Book *root,char *ntitle){
    if (root == NULL){
        cout<<"No Books found";
        return -1;
    }
    else if(ntitle == root->title){
        cout<<"Title:\t"<<root->title<<endl<<"URL:\t"<<root->url<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(ntitle[0] < root->title[0]){
        return search_Book(root->left,ntitle);
    }
    else {
        return search_Book(root->right,ntitle);
    }
}
int insert_Book(){
    char name[50];
    char title[100];
    char url[100];
    Student* node;
    cout<<"Enter the name of the student you want the book to be added to: ";
    cin>>name;
    node = searchstudent(name);
    if(node == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Enter the Title: ";
        cin>>title;
        cout<<"Enter the url: ";
        cin>>url;
        add_Book(node->bookTree,title,url);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insert()` uses `insert_Book()` and `search_Book()` before they are defined (as you define them after `insert()`).

Two solutions:

1- Move `insert_Book()` and `search_Book()` code before `insert()`

2- Or declare them before `insert()`: just write

```
int insert_Book();
int search_Book(Book *root,char *ntitle);
```

This tells the compiler not to worry, those will be implemented soon...you can implement them later, after `insert()`.